# Serving static files with Express.js on heroku. Where do files reside in Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, path, routes

**The issue** is Heroku can not find the files of my node project. This prompts the 404 Not found error. **The question** is how does the generic node Heroku file structure look like? If so, where do the files of my project actually reside in the heroku?

**The scenario:**

With the express library, I put all files needed to serve a frontend template, in a folder called 'public'. The absolute path leading to 'public' is needed and'_dirname' is the variable that contains that.

```
app.use(express.static(_dirname+'/public');
```

Now, Heroku always makes a GET request to the root of the application. As a response I send the
index.html file as the starting template. I also provide its absolute path as '{root:_dirname}'.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile('public/index.html'{root:_dirname});

});
```

When the server is run, I get a 404 Not found error. Which means Heroku cannot find the files.
Heroku root folder is named app/. So as expected, providing  the local '_dirname' is wrong since the application is now running on Heroku server not locally.

```
2020-09-10T15:28:12.127567+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/C:/Users/...
```

But, pointing at the public folder alone(only /public), assuming app/ is root, still prompts the 404 error not found.

```
2020-09-10T15:31:23.630358+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/index.html'
```

**The Question**

Which leads to the question, **what does heroku file structure look like? where do project files reside in the heroku file structure, so i can provide the correct path on the GET request?**

**My file structure**

[image]

After Bergur suggestion:

It prompts a 404 Not found. However, the path is now theoretically correct.
[image]

This is what I changed:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/public')));
```

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html',{root:__dirname+'/public'});
});
```

The 404 error comes from the 'app.get('/,function(req,res){});'. Without this handler, my heroku application shows a 'cannot GET' message on the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to log out the full path just to see if there's something off?

I have several heroku projects with nodejs and react/vue/angular dist folder without problems.

I would change your code a little bit to:

1. use nodes __dirname
2. Use path.join instead of inserting the '/' yourself. It might cause some problems.

So final version might look like:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

This assumes the project structure is

-index.js

-public/index.html

There should be no need to use sendFile, serving the public folder is enough. Just make sure that the public folder is being deployed/pushed to heroku.

If you share with us your folder/project structure we might help you you better.

Comment: Hi Bergur, I tried your suggestion. But it prompts the 404 Not found error. Theoretically, It should be correct because it now points to the right path.

Comment: What does the log say now?

Comment: This is my log now: :2020-09-10T17:38:00.904418+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/public/index.html'.   I used heroku logs --tail

Comment: Are you still using res.sendFile? It shouldnt be needed.

Comment: Yes. When i dont make use of it. I get the: Cannot GET error .

Comment: Hmm you shouldn't need it. Are you sure that your public folder is being deployed tp heroku?

Comment: When you commit/push to heroku, must you also commit /push to your original git project? Because, I did a 'git status' and it mentioned my 'public/ index.html' as an untracked file along with a number of commits pending.( Commits that i pushed only on heroku). Pushing to the original repo and pushing to the heroku repo. Made it work! In any case, I appreciate your help a lot Bergur for debugging and pointing out possible openings.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you're happy and my answers helped, I would appreciate if you could mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.